# Admin-only editable field of entry?

Tags: entries, field

I'm have group called "Editors" that can create entries with the text fields but I would like to "Admin" group have lightswitch called "promoted" in same entries or maybe even text field for notes that would be not visible for "Editors" group (and entry owner if he is in "Editors" group) it is possible?

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a non-terribly hacky way to pull this off in the current version of Craft, unfortunately.

You might want to consider adding a thumbs-up/comment to this feature request that would allow for what you're looking for: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/947